# Codeigniter- count number of null columns in a row

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, null

I am new to codeigniter and working on a project where I need some help.

I want to count the number of columns from a single row where fields are null. I know this can be done in normal SQL statement. But I want to learn how to do that in CI.

I searched for many hours on this community, but found some unexpected answers.

Yes I can do this for only one column using this statement :

```
$this->db->where('column_name' =>  NULL)
```

This is for single column. Do I have to do it for every column? Or I can do it in some better way.

Please help me to solve this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You.
Regards,
Vaibhav M

Comment: you can also pass  an array of columns into where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on only one row as would be the case using the following query

```
$row = $this->db
    ->get_where('table', ['id' => $value])
    ->row_array();
```

Then you could count the NULL values in the `$row` array like this

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($row as $column)
{
    if(! isset($column))
    {
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
```

The query depends on the `id` column having unique values.

If you want to check more than one row let me know and I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: as you said I'm working on just one row. That row consist profile data of user. I want to check the null values and show that on progress bar which will show in % of profile completion. I think this could help to tell what exactly my problem is. And thank you for your help I'll try this and will give you feedback soon.

Comment: Thanks buddy the code you provided is perfectly working for me. I have one question can I do this section in CI.

`foreach ($row as $column)
{
    if(! isset($column))
    {
        $count++;
    }
}`

Comment: You are asking if the code works in CI? The answer is yes. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: No I want to ask can I do the same working code using any CI function or library or any helper?

Comment: No, none that I can think of.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help buddy. If you found something related to I asked please let me know.